# Extract filename from file result in Ansible

Tags: regex, jenkins, ansible

I'm trying to use the result of Ansible `find` module, which return list of files it find on a specific folder.

The problem is, when I iterate over the result, I do not have the file names, I only have their full paths (including the name).

Is there an easy way to use the `find_result` `item`s below to provide the `file_name` in the second command as shown below?

```yaml
- name: get files
  find:
    paths: /home/me
    file_type: "file"
  register: find_result

- name: Execute docker secret create
  shell: docker secret create <file_name> {{ item.path }}
  run_once: true
  with_items: "{{ find_result.files }}"
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`basename` [filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters)?

```
{{ item.path | basename }}
```

There are also `dirname`, `realpath`, `relpath` filters.

Answer (score 4):

This question and accepted answer are great for the time they were written. However, I want to leave a note about the *current preferred* way of doing it.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-to-loop

> With the release of Ansible 2.5, the recommended way to perform loops is the use the new loop keyword instead of with_X style loops.

I've seen seen this common pattern evolve for such file-loop combinations.

```
- name: "Find python files in folder scripts"
  find:
    paths: "{{ playbook_dir }}/scripts"
    patterns: "*.py"
    file_type: "file"
  register: python_files

- name: "Execute those python scripts from the script folder"
  shell: "python {{ item.path | basename }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/scripts"
  loop: "{{ python_files.files }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path | basename }}"
```

This loops over a certain type of files in a directory (python files) and takes a certain action with their filename (executes them), and using their filename is justified because `chdir` puts you in the directory where those files are.

It's important to use that same filename in `loop_control` because otherwise it prints `item`, which isn't *just* the absolute path, but a dozen other file properties which is completely unreadable.

This works, but it also ignores the motivations for the `loop` changes to Ansible in the first place. This also works, replacing 2 tasks with 1:

```
- name: "Execute python scripts from the script folder"
  shell: "python {{ item | basename }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/scripts"
  with_fileglob: "{{ playbook_dir }}/scripts/*.py"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item | basename }}"
```

In this loop, `item` is the absolute path. You may prefer to print that, in which case lose the `loop_control` completely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the filename from the file path, becomes much easy. In your case:
{{find_result.path|basename}}

Comment: The accepted answer to this question, which is three years old, appears to cover this. When adding a new answer to an older question be sure to point out what new aspect of the question it addresses.

Comment: quote: much easy (without the bad english that becomes "much easier"), which is exactly the new aspect. if you don't know the tool in question well enough to judge an answers' merit, please don't try to.