# looping in Ansible templates directory

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I would like to write a loop for this Use Case:

I have an Ansible `templates` directory and inside this directory files with extension `.j2`, for example I have like this files.

```
data-service01.service.j2
data-relation.service.j2
data-query.service.j2
data-analysis.service.j2
```

So I want to write a task in Ansible to loop in `templates` directory to transfer files inside the `templates` to the destination by writing `src: data-*` it can loop to all files start with `data-` to transfer to directory.

Can I do this because I using the normal way

```yaml
 src: data-service01.service.j2
 dest: data-service01.service
```

But I want to looping inside `templates` directory by

```yaml
 src: data-*.j2
```

How I can do this with `loop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [`fileglob` lookup – list files matching a pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html)

> *Matching is against local system files on the Ansible controller.*

you may have a look into the following minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Template out each file that matches the given pattern
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "/tmp/{{ item.split('.') | first | basename }}.service"
    with_fileglob:
      - "templates/data-*.j2"
```

which

- [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with) from the `templates` directory `with_fileglob`
- [Extract file names without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61931335/6771046) and drops the path in order to generate the destination filename

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Template out each file that matches the given pattern] ****************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user/test/templates/data-relation.service.j2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user/test/templates/data-service01.service.j2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user/test/templates/data-query.service.j2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user/test/templates/data-analysis.service.j2)
```

and finally the requested files.

```bash
~/test$ ls /tmp/data-*
/tmp/data-analysis.service  /tmp/data-query.service  /tmp/data-relation.service  /tmp/data-service01.service
```

**Further Q&A and Documentation**

- [Extract filename from file result in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565068/6771046)
- [`basename` filter – get a path’s base name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/basename_filter.html)
- [Ansible: Copy files with wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116534/)